# Order by problem in List (linq related)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have a problem on how to order a list.
I have a list of products and i sort them by price. But in my db i have two prices : price and offer.

I want to sort my products by price , BUT if offer is >0 then i  want to sort by offer

I thought of this but it does not work:

```
list.OrderBy(p => p.offer != 0 ? p.offer : p.price );
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What is the error?  What is the expected vs. actual results?

Comment: @Smudge202 It oreders the list by price not considering the offer value

Comment: Is the code you use exactly like that?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Yes it is the same code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has said, `OrderBy` doesn't sort in place. It returns a `IOrderedEnumerable` (it's something similar to an `IEnumerable`, but ordered :-) ).

If you want to sort in place (**and you are using a `List<>`**) do this:

```
list.Sort((p, q) => (p.offer != 0 ? p.offer : p.price).CompareTo(q.offer != 0 ? q.offer : q.price));
```

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` does not sort in-place. It returns an ordered sequence without modifying the original. You need to assign the result:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(p => p.offer > 0 ? p.offer : p.price).ToList();
```

Comment: Nope.. still it does not consider offer value

Comment: @mathew: The code I posted works: http://www.ideone.com/H3etj. Maybe I misunderstood your requirements, or you have another problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a new list that contains a field called final price which is equal to offer if offer > 0, otherwise with price. Then sort, and then get the final list.

```
var new_list = list.Select(element => new { new_price = element.offer > 0 ? element.offer : element.price, element });
var ordered_new_list = new_list.OrderBy(element => element.new_price);
var ordered_List = ordered_new_list.Select(element => element.element);
```

Comment: I don't see how the behaviour of this code should differ from the original code posted (other than the missing assignment). Care to enlighten me? What am I missing here?